# Unity IoC Not Registering Types Correctly

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have a well known issue where my Web API complains that my controller does not have a parameterless constructor. I have been through many pages and questions on this but cant seem to find the issue.

I installed Unity using Nuget command `Install-Package Unity.WebAPI`. The UnityConfig was created properly.

This is my `UnityConfig` file:

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IImportHeadService, ImportHeadService>();
        container.RegisterType<IImportDetailService, ImportDetailService>();
        container.RegisterType<ICurrencyService, CurrencyService>();
        container.RegisterType<ISupplierService, SupplierService>();
        container.RegisterType<IKPIService, KPIService>();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
    }
}
```

I then registered the `UnityConfig` in my `Global.asax` file as below:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

And finally, here is my `ImportController` which is what I am trying to call through fiddler:

```
public class ImportController : ApiController
{
    private IImportHeadService _importHeadService;
    private IImportDetailService _importDetailService;

    public ImportController(IImportHeadService importHeadService, IImportDetailService importDetailService)
    {
        _importHeadService = importHeadService;
        _importDetailService = importDetailService;
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("api/Import/Info")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetInfo()
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Import Tracker v1.0 - Import Controller");
    }
}
```

As you can see it is a very simple controller at this point but I receive the following error:

`An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'ImportController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.`

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I was being a bit silly after all. My services have a parameter in their constructor for a context. Once I added the context into the Unity configuration. It all worked.